# Regex Difficulties Extracting Text for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have run the regex code below on my data in an online regex tester and it works fine.  However, when I attempt to run it in Python 3 and Pandas 0.18 I get NaN in the new 'r' column.

The regex codes is:

```
\(\(\d+,\s\d+\],\s\(\d+,\s(\d+)\]\)
```

Sample data is:

```
                   WT_g      r_25_text           r
Azmuth_25   Range_25            
(0, 5]      (0, 25]     1   ((0, 5],   (0, 25])     NaN
(25, 30]    (25, 50]    1   ((25, 30], (25, 50])    NaN
(35, 40]    (25, 50]    1   ((35, 40], (25, 50])    NaN
(65, 70]    (50, 75]    1   ((65, 70], (50, 75])    NaN
(85, 90]    (50, 75]    1   ((85, 90], (50, 75])    NaN
(95, 100]   (25, 50]    1   ((95, 100], (25, 50])   NaN
(100, 105]  (50, 75]    1   ((100, 105], (50, 75])  NaN
(110, 115]  (50, 75]    1   ((110, 115], (50, 75])  NaN
(115, 120]  (0, 25]     1   ((115, 120], (0, 25])   NaN
```

My code:

```
df_25_sum['r'] = df_25_sum['r_25_text'].str.extract('\(\(\d+,\s\d+\],\s\(\d+,\s(\d+)\]\)')
df_25_sum
```

The output is the sample data above.  I get NaN when I add the new column based on an extract.

Comment: Does it work if you put `r` before your regex string in your `extract` call? Also, your regex doesn't match the first item of `r_25_text` because it has more than one space in the middle - if you change it to `\(\(\d+,\s\d+\],\s+\(\d+,\s(\d+)\]\)` then it works.

Comment: Did you try to add a `+` after the `\s` : `\(\(\d+,\s\d+\],\s+\(\d+,\s(\d+)\]\)`. [pythex link](http://pythex.org/?regex=\%28\%28\d%2B%2C\s\d%2B\]%2C\s%2B\%28\d%2B%2C\s%28\d%2B%29\]\%29&test_string=%28%280%2C%205]%2C%20%20%20%280%2C%2025]%29%0A%28%2825%2C%2030]%2C%20%2825%2C%2050]%29&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: what is your expected output for the column `r`?

Comment: It is working fine for me. What is your expected o/p?

Comment: please look after extra spaces in `((0, 5],   (0, 25])`..maybe they are causing the problem

Comment: I'm looking to extract the 4 digit.  In rock321997 it would be 25

Comment: I updated the regex text to match OrangeFlash81's recommendation and added the r before the quotes but still only get NaN.  Here's what I did:  df_25_sum['r'] = df_25_sum['r_25_text'].str.extract(r'\(\(\d+,\s+\d+\],\s+\(\d+,\s+(\d+)\]\)').

Comment: You are missing several backslashes in your last comment.  Did you use Till's regex?

Comment: The frame in this example looks like a MultiIndex and differs from your answer.  For clarity what which datastructure were you using in your original post?

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually trying to extract the last digits from `r_25_text` (according to your comment), the follow regex pattern should work:

```
pattern = r'(\d+)(?=(\]\)))'            # find digits next to '])'

df_25_sum['r'] = df_25_sum['r_25_text'].str.extract(pattern)
df_25_sum
```

The output for the `r` column should be the last numeric values in each row of column `r_25_text`, i.e. `25, 50, 50, 75, 75`, etc.

See the [regex link](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cd%2B)(%3F%3D(%5C%5D%5C)))&test_string=((0%2C%205%5D%2C%20%20%20(0%2C%2025%5D)%0A((25%2C%2030%5D%2C%20(25%2C%2050%5D)%20%0A((100%2C%20105%5D%2C%20(50%2C%2075%5D)%0A((115%2C%20120%5D%2C%20(0%2C%20725%5D)%0A%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: I used your code, but still get NaN in the new 'r' column.  I'm beginning to think that this is not a regex problem but a Pandas one.  I like the improved regex code though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.  It is essentially the same answer that pylang developed.  But I could not get the regex pattern to work with the '=' sign.  My final code and regex pattern was:

```
pattern = r'(\d+)?\]'            # find digits next to ']'
df_25_sum['r'] = df_25_sum['r_25_text'].str.extract(pattern)


Azmuth_25    Range_25   WT_g  r_25_text r               
(0, 5]      (0, 25]     1     (0, 25]   25
(25, 30]    (25, 50]    1     (25, 50]  50
(35, 40]    (25, 50]    1     (25, 50]  50
(65, 70]    (50, 75]    1     (50, 75]  75
(85, 90]    (50, 75]    1     (50, 75]  75
```

I can only assume that Pandas 0.18 does not support the '=' in regex.  Thanks again [pylang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531270/pylang).

Comment: Glad you got what you wanted.  I notice the 4th column is different.  I'm curious to know how you resolved this case `((0, 5],   (0, 25])` from your original post?  Your new regex pattern selects the 2nd and last numbers (5 and 25).  This is different than your request, so what has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
import pandas as pd

df_25_sum = pd.DataFrame([
    '((0, 5],   (0, 25])',
    '((25, 30], (25, 50])',
    '((35, 40], (25, 50])'
    ], columns=['r_25_text'])

pattern = r'\(\(\d+,\s\d+\],\s+\(\d+,\s(\d+)\]\)' 

df_25_sum['r'] = df_25_sum['r_25_text'].str.extract(pattern)

df_25_sum

>>>>               r_25_text   r
     0   ((0, 5],   (0, 25])  25
     1  ((25, 30], (25, 50])  50
     2  ((35, 40], (25, 50])  50
```